# Clustering on a Map using R and Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny, googlevis

I am using leaflet in R (Just Starting to use it). I like the how the clustering/visualization is done in the post below.  The programmer is using Java.  What I can not find for leaflet / R, is how to create a cluster circle with number, that is a summary of the number of markers, which response to the number of markers present responding to zooming.  I can get the different markers on the map, but not the response to zooming.

Example
[Leaflet Simple CSV](http://blog.perrygeo.net/2013/09/30/leaflet-simple-csv)

http://blog.perrygeo.net/2013/09/30/leaflet-simple-csv

If this is is not possible in R/leaflet.  What I am trying to show is: one zip code has 10 visits and one zip code has 1 visit.  I want to use R/Shiny to create the project. If leaflet is not the best I am open to other options (googlevis?)I am new to mapping so I might be missing something simple...

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This feature is documented [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html) in the section "Marker Clusters".

You just need to add the option `clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()` to your `addMarkers()` call.

Comment: It's so simple it feels like cheating